# Haskell - Create a fold function for tree type

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

I have this simple data Tree :

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node [Tree]
```

And I have to devellop a fold function for this type :

```
foldTree :: (Int -> a) -> ([a] -> a) -> Tree -> a
```

for example :

```
foldTree (+1) sum (Node[ (Leaf 2), (Leaf 3)])
```

will return (2+1)+(3+1) = 7
For leafs, I have :

```
foldTree f g (Leaf n)  = (f n)
```

But I have no ideas for develop the nodes's case.

I'm french, also sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: hint: how do you obtain a list of `a`s from a list of `Tree`s?

Answer (score 3):

It sometimes helps to look at what is available in scope and their types. Here's a solution:

```
foldTree f g (Leaf n)  = (f n)
foldTree f g (Node subtrees)  = 
  let as = map (foldTree f g) subtrees -- as :: [a]
  in g as
```